# プッシュ通知で出来る事

Tags: ios, android, monaca, push-notification

お世話になっております。
現在バックエンドサービスのプッシュ通知機能利用を検討しております。

そこで質問なのですが、プッシュ通知というのは、基本的に端末への
お知らせorアプリの起動にしか使えないのでしょうか？

他に出来そうな事があれば、教えて頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

プッシュ通知でなにができるかはアイデア次第だと思います。

承知のことと思いますが、プッシュ通知にはペイロードを含めることができます。
なので、アプリはそのペイロードを受け取ってペイロードの情報を元に何らかの処理を実行します。

例えばペイロードに電話番号を含めて、プッシュ通知を受け取ったアプリが勝手にその電話番号に電話をかけるとか。

あくまで、プッシュ通知は外部からアプリを起動する手段であり、そこから何をするかはアプリが決める事になります。
なので、考え方としては、アプリでできることならなんでも出来ると思ってもらえればいいと思います。

Comment: ご回答頂き有難うございます。アプリを起動させる手段だったんですね。受け取った値を元に処理を実行できるのであれば、いろいろできそうですね・・・。ご回答頂き有難うございました！